# Eclipse. Tomcat doesn't unpack and deploy war file

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have configured Eclipse to use tomcat server.
I put my war file to

```
C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.68\webapps
```

Eclipse says that the server started and running, but I can't reach my project using

```
localhost:8080/example
```

also

```
C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.68\webapps
```

directory doesn't contain unpacked `example.war` file.
`Server.xml` file contains the following line:

```
<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
```

Comment: Eclipse has its own configuration for tomcat.  You should consider modifying the Server.xml directly from within eclipse rather than modify the installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that by default Eclipse starts server in different location and that's why you need to change it.

Double click on your `tomcat` server in `Eclipse` servers tab.
In `Overview` window expand `Server locations` and select:

`Use Tomcat installation (takes control of Tomcat installation)`